# How to replace the button when the user is not authenticated?

Tags: 8, theming

I copied the twig file of my nodes into my theme.

On my nodes there is a flag displayed, but only authenticated users can see it.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="bs-field-like-link">
  {{ content.flag_like_group }}
</div>
```

How to replace the flag for unauthenticated users by :

```
<div class="bs-field-like-link">
  <a class="btn btn-success" href="/user/login"><i class="far fa-heart fa-1x"></i> J'aime</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Specifying URLs directly is not a good practice. Instead consider using `url()` Twig function which allow to build a URL by route name. This would allow to avoid possible issues with path aliases, domains, languages and so on.

Comment: @ya.teck thanks, can you give me an example with url login ?

Comment: `{{ url('user.login') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predefined `logged_in` variable.

```
{% if logged_in %}
  <div class="bs-field-like-link">
    {{ content.flag_like_group }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="bs-field-like-link">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/user/login"><i class="far fa-heart fa-1x"></i> J'aime</a>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```